# Multiple Exceptions in hibernate code using MyEclipse

Tags: java, xml, hibernate, exception

I am doing a hibernate  mapping many-to-one project . Wherein Students class maps Saddress class. I am doing the project using MyEclipse but the hibernate project is throwing few exceptions. Here i tried to rectify the code with the suggestions in StackOverflow. But of no use; also because the code i am using is already defined , the hibernate.cfg.xml file or Students.hbm.xml file or Saddress.hbm.xml file , these files are generated automatically, so no question of error. I am unable to identify error.

hibernate.cfg.xml -

```
  <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
  <!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
      "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
      "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
   <!-- Generated by MyEclipse Hibernate Tools.                   -->
   <hibernate-configuration>

    <session-factory>
    <mapping resource="studentonetomany/Students.hbm.xml" />
    <mapping resource="studentonetomany/Saddress.hbm.xml" />

    </session-factory>

    </hibernate-configuration>
```

Students.java -

```
 package studentonetomany;

 import java.util.HashSet;
 import java.util.Set;

 /**
  * Students entity. @author MyEclipse Persistence Tools
  */

  public class Students implements java.io.Serializable {

    // Fields

private Integer sid;
private String sname;
private Integer age;
private Set saddresses = new HashSet(0);

// Constructors

/** default constructor */
public Students() {
}

/** minimal constructor */
public Students(Integer sid) {
    this.sid = sid;
}

/** full constructor */
public Students(Integer sid, String sname, Integer age) {
    this.sid = sid;
    this.sname = sname;
    this.age = age;

}

// Property accessors

public Integer getSid() {
    return this.sid;
}

public void setSid(Integer sid) {
    this.sid = sid;
}

public String getSname() {
    return this.sname;
}

public void setSname(String sname) {
    this.sname = sname;
}

public Integer getAge() {
    return this.age;
}

   public void setAge(Integer age) {
    this.age = age;
    }

    public Set getSaddresses() {
        return this.saddresses;
    }

    public void setSaddresses(Set saddresses) {
        this.saddresses = saddresses;
  }

}
```

Saddress.java

```
  package studentonetomany;

 /**
  * Saddress entity. @author MyEclipse Persistence Tools
  */

 public class Saddress implements java.io.Serializable {

// Fields

private Integer aid;
private Students students;
private String street;
private String city;
private String state;

// Constructors

/** default constructor */
public Saddress() {
}

/** minimal constructor */
public Saddress(Integer aid) {
    this.aid = aid;
}

/** full constructor */
public Saddress(Integer aid, Students students, String street, String city, 
 String state) {
    this.aid = aid;
    this.students = students;
    this.street = street;
    this.city = city;
    this.state = state;
}

// Property accessors

public Integer getAid() {
    return this.aid;
}

public void setAid(Integer aid) {
    this.aid = aid;
}

public Students getStudents() {
    return this.students;
}

public void setStudents(Students students) {
    this.students = students;
}

public String getStreet() {
    return this.street;
}

public void setStreet(String street) {
    this.street = street;
}

public String getCity() {
    return this.city;
}

public void setCity(String city) {
    this.city = city;
}

public String getState() {
    return this.state;
}

public void setState(String state) {
    this.state = state;
}

 }
```

Saddress.hbm.xml file

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 
  3.0//EN"
  "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- 
Mapping file autogenerated by MyEclipse Persistence Tools
 -->
 <hibernate-mapping>
<class name="studentonetomany.Saddress" table="saddress" 
 catalog="testingcampus">
    <id name="aid" type="java.lang.Integer">
        <column name="aid" />
        <generator class="assigned" />
    </id>
    <many-to-one name="students" class="studentonetomany.Students" 
    fetch="select">
        <column name="sid" />
    </many-to-one>
    <property name="street" type="java.lang.String">
        <column name="street" length="20" />
    </property>
    <property name="city" type="java.lang.String">
        <column name="city" length="20" />
    </property>
    <property name="state" type="java.lang.String">
        <column name="state" length="20" />
    </property>
</class>
 </hibernate-mapping>
```

Students.hbm.xml file -

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 
  3.0//EN"
  "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
  <!-- 
    Mapping file autogenerated by MyEclipse Persistence Tools
    -->
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="studentonetomany.Students" table="students" catalog="testingcampus">
    <id name="sid" type="java.lang.Integer">
        <column name="sid" />
        <generator class="assigned" />
    </id>
    <property name="sname" type="java.lang.String">
        <column name="sname" length="20" />
    </property>
    <property name="age" type="java.lang.Integer">
        <column name="age" />
    </property>
    <set name="saddresses" inverse="true">
        <key>
            <column name="sid" />
        </key>
        <one-to-many class="studentonetomany.Saddress" />
    </set>
   </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Main Program -
SMapping.java

```
 package studentonetomany;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;

public class SMapping {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    Session session = HibernateSessionFactory.getSession();

    Transaction t = session.beginTransaction();

    Students st = new Students(100,"pravin",29);

    Saddress addr1 = new Saddress(1,st,"BTM","Bangalore","Karnataka");

    Saddress addr2 = new Saddress(2,st,"Rajaji 
    Nagar","Bangalore","Karnataka");



    session.save(st);
    session.save(addr1);
    session.save(addr2);

    t.commit();


 }

 }
```

Error -

```
Jan 09, 2018 10:35:54 PM 
org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.ConnectionProviderInitiator 
initiateService
WARN: HHH000181: No appropriate connection provider encountered, assuming 
application will be supplying connections
%%%% Error Creating SessionFactory %%%%
org.hibernate.HibernateException: Connection cannot be null when 
   'hibernate.dialect' not set
     at 


org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1742)
at studentonetomany.HibernateSessionFactory.<clinit>
(HibernateSessionFactory.java:34)
at studentonetomany.SMapping.main(SMapping.java:10)
Jan 09, 2018 10:35:54 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration configure
INFO: HHH000043: Configuring from resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
Jan 09, 2018 10:35:54 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration 
getConfigurationInputStream
INFO: HHH000040: Configuration resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
Jan 09, 2018 10:35:54 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration addResource
 INFO: HHH000221: Reading mappings from resource: 
 studentonetomany/Students.hbm.xml
  Jan 09, 2018 10:35:54 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration addResource
  INFO: HHH000221: Reading mappings from resource: 
  studentonetomany/Saddress.hbm.xml
  Jan 09, 2018 10:35:55 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration doConfigure
  INFO: HHH000041: Configured SessionFactory: null
   Jan 09, 2018 10:35:55 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MappingsImpl 
  addImport
  INFO: HHH000071: Duplicate import: studentonetomany.Students -> 
     studentonetomany.Students
  Jan 09, 2018 10:35:55 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MappingsImpl 
  addImport
   INFO: HHH000071: Duplicate import: studentonetomany.Students -> Students
   %%%% Error Creating SessionFactory %%%%
    org.hibernate.InvalidMappingException: Could not parse mapping document 
    from 
         resource studentonetomany/Students.hbm.xml
    at ....

     ... 7 more
     Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
     at studentonetomany.SMapping.main(SMapping.java:12)
```

Answer (score 0):

For some reason I dont know why your configuration dont have something like this:

```
<session-factory>
    <property name = "dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</property>
    <property name = "connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>

    <property name = "connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/mydb</property>

    <property name = "connection.username">root</property>
    <property name = "connection.password">12345</property>
</session-factory>
```

Comment: I added the piece of code in my hibernate.cfg.xml file. But the Multiple exceptions continue to appear - [1] 
 org.hibernate.service.classloading.spi.ClassLoadingException: Specified JDBC Driver com.mysql.jdbc.Driver class not found  [2]Caused by: org.hibernate.service.classloading.spi.ClassLoadingException: Unable to load class [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver]   [3 ] Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Could not load requested class : com.mysql.jdbc.Driver   [4]  org.hibernate.InvalidMappingException: Could not parse mapping document from resource studentonetomany/Students.hbm.xml

Comment: update your question and provide what database you are using. My answer use MySql as example.